# ANTLR's AST tree updating

Tags: c#, antlr

I use Lexer and Parser classes generated by ANTLR tool (targeting C#). Assume I have parsed some code and got an AST tree for it. What if part of my initial code has changed and I want to update just the corresponding parts of the tree? Is there a common way to do that?
For example a line of code was inserted inside some functions body. And I want to rebuild just the part of the tree representing this function and update positions of subsequent functions tokens

Comment: After you've changed the tree, what do you want to do next? I assume, regenerate source text.  With comments? Original layout? ...?

Comment: I just want to have relevant AST tree. Let's say I want to manage the intellisense for some IDE

Comment: How would you know what parts of your AST actually were affected by the change?

Comment: Every AST node is labeled with its position inside the original text. At least we can safely assume that every node located before the parent of the one containing altered fragment is unchanged. Then we could reparse the fragment representing the parent of the changed node and somehow check if it didn't represent any changes (like unclosed constructions) that could broke the nodes located after it. If everything is safe we just replace the changed node with the new one and relabel the tree with new text positions. Otherwise we should parse the rest of the code

Comment: I thought that was a good idea but it seems like nobody really does this kind of things in the real life and there's no proven algorithm for that. ) It probably wouldn't even be time-saving

Comment: I think that is in fact the question to be answered, does it save time to analyse what nodes changed or were affected rather then reparse and regenerate the AST. Do you have performance troubles yet with regenerating the AST?

Comment: I've partially adopted the technique used in Eclipse IDE. They have a thing called 'diet parser' which skips functions bodies and processes only global information (like functions signatures and fields). So usually they need to fully reparse only the body of the recently changed function. After all having your intellisense information few hundreds milliseconds outdated is not such a big deal. But I think a true incremental parser would be more elegant solution and a fun thing to do

Comment: Would that imply you'd have some kind of multi hierarchy parser, as you would separate parsers for bodys, fields etc.? I'm just thinking aloud...

Comment: There is a class taking information from both global and current function's trees and delivering it for intellisense managing module. I wouldn't call it a parser whatsoever. And of course it's only suitable for this particular task, you don't want to do something like that when building a compiler for instance.

Comment: I was thinking about this recently because I have an ANTLR grammar that I'd like to use to make an Eclipse syntax-highlighting plug-in.  Right now, I'm just re-parsing the entire file for every change, and just dealing with the lagging interface.  Please update if you come up with a solution to your problem.

Comment: No news here, I'm still using the same approach having 2 trees parsed separately: one for the current function and the other for the whole file. I don't do it on the UI thread so no interface lagging. :) As far as I've seen, text editors developers usually don't build syntax tree just for highlighting purposes. Instead they implement more lightweight string pattern matching (which actually allows to reanalyze only a small part of the text on every change). But probably you wouldn't like to do such an analysis on the UI thread as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few projects out there which do what you might want to accomplish.
But I don't know if ANTLR supports this.
You might take a look at: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incremental_compiler

For syntax highlighting propose only, I suggest using regular expression for the different token in your syntax. (If you update just the line you're working on you should not get any performance problems.)